# Python program error at closing

Tags: python

I hope you can help me once again, I am still noob at programming so please bear with me. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cx_Freeze exe Creator\Postcodezoekernl.py", line 136, in <module>
    postcodeinvoer = int(postcodeinvoer)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

The program works, but when I compile it, it will give an error when you close the program, saying there is something wrong with the code. I've tried deleting the line but the program wont work without it as it will go directly to the ELSE statement. Postcode1 is a range between certain numbers. The users have to fill in a number. If the number is within that range it will show the msgbox.

```
elif keuze in week2:

        postcodeinvoer = easygui.enterbox(msg="Voer een postcode in:", title="Postcodezoeker")
        postcodeinvoer = int(postcodeinvoer)

        if postcodeinvoer in postcode1:
            easygui.msgbox(msg="[Woensdag 3 mei, 10 mei, 17 mei, 24 mei] [Donderdag 4 mei, 11 mei, 18 mei]", title=postcodeinvoer)
        elif postcodeinvoer in postcode2:
            easygui.msgbox(msg="[Dinsdag 2 mei, 9 mei, 16 mei, 23 mei] [Donderdag 4 mei, 11 mei, 18 mei]", title=postcodeinvoer)
        elif postcodeinvoer in postcode3:
            easygui.msgbox(msg="[Dinsdag 2 mei, 9 mei, 16 mei, 23 mei] [Donderdag 4 mei, 11 mei, 18 mei]", title=postcodeinvoer)
```

Btw is it possible to compile a python file to a single .exe file?
Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Problem resolved!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check `postcodeinvoer`is not None.

```
if postcodeinvoer:
    postcodeinvoer = int(postcodeinvoer)
```

Comment: It will always be `None`; it's the value returned by widget creation. They have to retrieve the widget's contained value.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That might not be true either if I understand the documentation right, see http://easygui.sourceforge.net/api.html#easygui.enterbox :  `Returns: 
the text that the user entered, or None if he cancels the operation.`

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: So in my opinion and if I understand the situation in the question right, this is actually a correct answer: when a user cancels the dialog, the `postcodeinvoer` will have `None` as it's value and the program will crash with this exact error. Obviously the if-condition will prevent that in this situation.

Comment: So I have to make an if statement above the enterbox with if postcodeinvoer == none, break. Else: the rest of the code?

Comment: First you want to explicitely test against `None` - because thare are other things than `None` that have a false value in a boolean test - , then you want to put the `int()` call in a try/except block - because quite a few non-`None` (and non-false) values won't be accepted by `int()`.

Comment: I have fixed it with the answer Surajano gave me. Add an IF statement.

Comment: @MrJ. ok now type some non numeric test in your box and see how it "solved" your problem...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've tried it and as you implied it resulted in an error. I've also check your fix down below. But i have no clue as how to apply it in my code. Could you please explain it a bit further. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`int(something)` will raise either a `TypeError` or a `ValueError` if it can instanciate an int from it's argument, so the simplest solution is to catch the exception and try again. But since we want to allow the user to cancel the operation we will still test againt `None` and exit instead

```
cancel = False
basemsg = msg = "Voer een postcode in:"
while True:
    postcodeinvoer = easygui.enterbox(msg=msg, title="Postcodezoeker")
    if postcodeinvoer is None:
        # user canceled
        cancel = True
        break
    try:
        postcodeinvoer = int(postcodeinvoer)
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        msg = "invalid value ! " + basemsg
    else:
        # ok, let's get out
        break

if cancel:
     # exit the program or whatever...
     raise SysExit()

# ok, proceed with the user's value
```

Now you seem to be making a common newbie mistake which is to think that if something is made up of digits then it's a number, which is NOT the case. A postal code or phone number are typically strings, not integers - ask yourself what sense it would make to multiply a phone number by 2 and divide the result by a postal code ;)

IOW, you should not convert `postcodeinvoer` to an `int` at all. If you're country's postal code are only made up of digits (which is not the case in all countries), then you can test that the user input is a string made of `N` digits (the value of `N` depending on your country):

```
    postcodeinvoer = easygui.enterbox(msg=msg, title="Postcodezoeker")
    if postcodeinvoer is None:
        # user canceled
        cancel = True
        break
    if (postcodeinvoer.isdigit() and len(postcodeinvoer) == N):
        # valid code
        break
    else:
        # invalid code, ask again
        msg = "invalid value ! " + basemsg
```

but even then it might not be a good enough validation...

Comment: I am getting an error after compiling it. If i would post the complete code and the sutup.py for cx_freeze post, could you give it a look please?

Comment: @MrJ. Sorry but this is not a  free"fix-my-code-for-me" service here - you have to understand the answers and code samples and fix your own code by yourself.  You're of course free to post another question regarding your "compiling error" but you may want to make sure the problem (and solution) are not obvious from the error message / traceback.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to fix it otherwise I will post a question. Thanks again!